# middle number without using median function, Python

Tags: python, median

I have been looking for how to find the middle number in the list so that I do not use the median function, but cannot find the information how to do that.

I need to write a code which takes middle(L) function (have to define it), makes a list L as its argument, and returns the item in the middle position of L. (In order that the middle is well-defined, i should assume that L has odd length.)

It is all i have right now and actually have no idea how to do that.

```
def middle (L):
    i= len((L)[0:-1])/2
    return i
print (middle)
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use the median function?

Comment: @RyneEverett Sounds like a school assignment, and that was one of the requirements. Not that uncommon. They often have students re-implement features just to have a better understanding of how they work (e.g. various sorts, trees, hashing, etc).

Answer (score 4):

To find the median, just sort the list and return the number in the middle position or (if the list has even number of elements), return the average of the 2 elements in middle:

```
def middle(L):
    L = sorted(L)
    n = len(L)
    m = n - 1
    return (L[n/2] + L[m/2]) / 2.0
```

---

Example:

```
>>> print middle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
3.0
>>> print middle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

As NPE's answer suggests you just have to get the middle element of a sorted list when the list  has  an uneven number of elements, if it has an even number of elements you take the average of the middle two elements:

```
def median(l):
    srt = sorted(l)
    mid = len(l)//2
    if len(l) % 2: # f list length mod 2 has a remainder the list is an odd lenght
            return srt[mid]
    else:
        med = (srt[mid] + srt[mid-1]) / 2  # in a list [1,2,3,4] srt[mid]-> 2, srt[mid-1] -> 3
        return med
```

Comment: This isn't necessary; as the question says, "In order that the middle is well-defined, i should assume that L has odd length." It might still be useful for other people with _different_ assignments, but for this one, he'd probably get dinged for not reading the instructions.

Comment: @abarnert, I am aware of that but I still think adding how to  to get the median of a list of values when the list is even is useful

Comment: That's why I said "It might still be useful for other people with *different* assignments".

Comment: @abarnert, well I guess we agree it is useful then

Answer (score 0):

For optimization, we should use binary search to detect the median, rather than to sort all numbers.
For details, please check: 
https://www.quora.com/Given-a-list-of-unsorted-numbers-how-would-you-find-the-median-without-sorting-the-original-array

For the code, please check:
https://medium.com/@nxtchg/calculating-median-without-sorting-eaa639cedb9f

There are two well-known ways to calculate median:

1. naive way (sort, pick the middle)
2. using quickselect (or similar algorithm for weighted median)

Hope it helps.